# Is there a way to block on a socket send() until we get the ack for that packet?

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming, sockets

Or do I have to implement it at the application level?

Answer (score 13):

I also faced the same problem few weeks ago when implementing a VoIP server. After spending several days I could come up with a solution. As many others mentioned, there is no any direct system call to do the job. Instead,

1. You can check if we have received the `ACK` after sending a packet with `TCP_INFO` option.
2. If we haven't received the `ACK`, wait for few milliseconds and check again.

This may continue until a time out reaches. You have to implement it as a wrapper function to send() call.
You will need `tcp_info` struct from `<netinet/tcp.h>`. It is the data structure for holding information about your *tcp connection*.

Here is the pseudo code

```
int blockingSend(const char *msg, int msglen, int timeout) {

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(write_mutx);

    int sent = send(sock_fd, msg, msglen,  0); 

    tcp_info info;
    auto expireAt = chrono::system_clock::now() + chrono::milliseconds(timeout);
    do {
        this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(50));
        getsockopt(sock_fd,SOL_TCP, TCP_INFO, (void *) &info, sizeof(info));

      //wait till all packets acknowledged or time expires
    } while (info.tcpi_unacked > 0 && expireAt > system_clock::now());

    if(info.tcpi_unacked>0) {
        cerr << "no of unacked packets :" << info.tcpi_unacked << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return sent;
}
```

Here `tcpi_unacked` member holds the number of packets **unacknowledged** of your connection. If you read it soon after the send() call, it will contain number of *unacked* packets which is equal to number of packets sent. With time, number of *unacked* packets will be decremented to zero. Therefore you need to periodically check the value of `tcpi_unacked` till it reaches zero. If the connection is half opened, you will never receive `ACK`s while causing a endless loop. For such scenarios you may need to add a **timeout** mechanism as implemented above.

*Even though this question has been asked long ago, this answer may help some one who has faced the same problem. I must mention that there could be more accurate solutions to this problem than this solution. Since I am a newbie to system programming and C/C++ this is what I could come up with.*

Comment: Thanks for the great answer TMtech :)

Comment: Your answer states, "If the connection is half opened, you will never receive ACKs while causing a endless loop.". Why wouldn't ACKs be received if a connection is half-opened? ACKs occur on both streams independently. Also, you say, "[...] after sending a packet with TCP_INFO option." I don't think TCP_INFO sends any packets, but it's simply a non-portable way to query the number of outstanding packets from the local kernel.

Comment: @kgibm If ACKs occur on both streams independently how come, the sender knows that receiver has received the packet which was sent? Note this is TCP, not UDP. If you need more information regarding the protocol please refer the following link
http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/7/understanding-tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers/

Comment: @kgibm It should be ... after sending a packet, with TCP_INFO option. Of course, TCP_INFO does not send any packets since it's a just a flag. If you could understand my code snippet, you might have noticed that TCP_INFO is used as an argument to the getsockopt(). It's simply a flag to getsockopt() indicating how to handle the pointer passed in the fourth argument.
It is obvious that system programming is tightly coupled with the system itself. This answer is for the people who have spent hours and days thinking about how to do it the correct way rather than choosing the easy way.

Comment: @TMtech Yes, it was a useful answer, thanks! Just wanted to clarify some of the statements in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

TCP will in general require you to synchronize the receiver and sender at the application level. Combinations of `SO_SNDBUF` tweaking or [`TCP_NODELAY`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) alone are not likely solve the problem completely. This is because the amount of data that can be "in flight" before `send()` will block is more or less equal to the sum of:

1. The data in the transmit side's send buffer, including small data fragments being delayed by [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm),
2. The amount of data carried in unacknowledged in-flight packets, which varies with the [congestion window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congestion_window) (`CWIN`) and receive window (`RWIN`) sizes. The TCP sender continuously tunes the congestion window size to network conditions as TCP transitions between slow-start, congestion avoidance, fast-recovery, and fast-retransmit modes. And,
3. Data in the receive side's receive buffer, for which the receiver's TCP stack will have already sent an `ACK`, but that the application has not yet seen.

To say it another way, after the receiver stops reading data from the socket, `send()` will only block when:

1. The receiver's TCP receive buffer fills and TCP stops `ACK`ing,
2. The sender transmits un`ACK`ed data up to the congestion or receive window limit, and
3. The sender's TCP send buffer fills or the sender application requests a send buffer flush.

The goal of the algorithms used in TCP is to create the effect of a flowing stream of bytes rather than a sequence of packets. In general it tries to hide as much as possible the fact that the transmission is quantized into packets at all, and most socket APIs reflect that. One reason for this is that sockets may not be implemented on top TCP (or indeed even IP) at all: consider a Unix domain socket, which uses the same API.

Attempting to rely on TCP's underlying implementation details for application behavior is generally not advisable. Stick to synchronizing at the application layer.

If latency is a concern in the situation where you're doing the synchronization, you may also want to read about [interactions between Nagle's algorithm and delayed `ACK`](http://www.stuartcheshire.org/papers/NagleDelayedAck/) that can introduce unnecessary delays in certain circumstances.

Comment: There can't be any more data in flight than is in the socket send buffer, by definition, so to add the two together is meaningless. Data in the receiver's socket receive buffer is not in flight. The total amount of data in flight is given by (2) alone.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about TCP, then no - no socket API I've seen allows you to do this.

You need to implement the ack in your application protocol if you need to be sure that the other end had received(and possibly processed) your data.

Answer (score 1):

The ack for the packet is at the transport layer (well below the application layer). You are not even guaranteed to have your entire buffer belong to its own packet on the network. What is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a blocking socket?

This may be a bit dated, but here is some explanation on blocking/non-blocking and overlapping IO.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181611

It would help if we knew which language and OS you were using, BTW, to better show code snippets.

Comment: It won't help. Blocking sockets block until you successfully pass your data to the OS network stack not until you receive the other party's ack... I'm using C on Linux btw...

Comment: But you can block until you receive the response, which could be the acknowledgment.

Comment: It seems that even a blocking write can successfully return before ACKs are received. POSIX says, "Successful completion of a call to send() does not guarantee delivery of the message."

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`setsockopt()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) to lower [`SO_SNDBUF`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html) to a value only large enough to send one packet, then the next `send()` on that socket should block until the previous packet is acknowledged.  However, according to [`tcp(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/tcp.7.html), the socket buffer size must be set prior to `listen()`/`connect()`.

Comment: Of source the trick is knowing the exact size of a single packet (aka the MTU ). Either way this method will probably result in a performance decrease, but that may not matter to the OP.

Comment: If the messages sent by the application are a small fixed size, e.g. 512 bytes, and only one is sent at a time, then there is no need to know the MTU.

Comment: Until you end up in a congested situation and the OS figures "lets try sending smaller segments".

Comment: The socket *receive* buffer needs to be set before `listen()/connect()` *if and only if* it is larger than 65535, so that an appropriate window scale can be negotiated during the handshake. There is no requirement to set the socket send buffer at that time, or the socket receive buffer either if it is less than 64k bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using TCP is to hide that individual ACK from applications. If you need to detect every ACK, then implement your own protocol using UDP or IP. TCP is probably an overkill. Or you can go up the stack and use a protocol like HTTP as a transport.