# How can I explicitly wait for a TCP ACK before proceeding?

Tags: c, tcp, sockets

Is there a way to get send() to wait until all the data that has been sent has been ACK-ed (or return -1 if the timeout for an ACK has been reached), or is there some other mechanism to wait for the ACK after the send() but before doing something else?

I am using the standard Unix Berkeley sockets API.

I know I could implement an application-layer ACK, but I'd rather not do that when TCP's ACK serves the purpose perfectly well.

Comment: You are wrong, TCP ACK does not serve that purpose. It tells sender's kernel that receiver's kernel got the bytes, not the target app (which might not even reading anything from the socket).

Comment: Before you start throwing around words like "TCP ACK" you might want to take the trouble to  understand how ACK is implemented and what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately standard API doesn't reserve any appropriate way to do this. There *could* be a way to query the current TCP send window size/usage, but unfortunately it may not be queried by the standard means.

Of course there are tricky ways to achieve what you want. For instance on Windows one may create a network filter driver to monitor packet-level trafic.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK there is no way.

Also, it wouldn't be reliable, the ACK means only that the kernel received the data, in the meantime the client or its machine could have crashed. You would think the client received the data, but actually it never processed it.

Comment: That isn't accurate.  The ack does not come from your local kernel, it comes from the remote side's kernel code as Nikolai mentions above.  So it is an assurance that the packet made it to the remote endpoint, but not necessarily that the remote userland app read it.

Comment: @TJD: I was talking about the remote kernel, I thought it's obvious.

Comment: @yi_H, it was unclear because you said the "client or its machine could have crashed".  It wasn't clear to me that you meant the client machine could have crashed after the kernel acked it but before the client app read the data.

Comment: Correct answer and one of the misunderstood parts of TCP. Most applications _need_ to have a application level response for every request. The ACK structure simply doesn't help because it's the remote kernel's receive. And you should update your response to clearly be the remote kernel as you intended.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have found a solution.  At least on Linux, if you set SO_SNDBUF to a value of 0, it seems to wait for every transaction before allowing the next transfer through.  While it will immediately return, it will not proceed to allowing another send to succeed until the previous send has sent.  I haven't tried using select(...) to determine if the data has been sent.

This works on my Linux 3.8 kernel, and am confident it works elsewhere.

Comment: I tried this on a 6.0.0 kernel and did not observe the same behavior (just as an FYI for people running more recent kernels)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a wrapper for send(). I have answered a question similar to this in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35599867/2307470).