# C# Socket send truncate info

Tags: c#, sockets

Iam tring to send a file using a socket, but almost always it cuts the file over the transmission, but the socket never sends an exception, it just does not send all the file.

Trying to solve this im sending the lenght of the file as a header to the server, so it could validate if the file is complete, if not it send a signal back asking for retransmition.

This works, but some times it takes up to 250 tries to get the file well, ¿what do you thinks is happening?,  I have in mind sending the file in smaller chunks, but what is a good size for the chunk?,

The files that fails to be send are of a size of 80kb, and some times even a file of 20kb fails!.

any tips?

Comment: Code of your main loop would be useful, even if pseudo-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sending the file data, you can use the Flush() method to force sending of all local buffered data.
When sending, TCP breaks the data up into small packets.

When reading data, the Read() method returns an integer which is the number of bytes actually read.
Always make sure that the amount you intended to read is the amount that was read.

```
int actuallyRead = stream.Read(bufferToStoreData, 0, bytesToRead);
while (actuallyRead < bytesToRead) {
    actuallyRead  += stream.Read(bufferToStoreData, actuallyRead, bytesToRead - actuallyRead);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a "Flush" method in the System.Net.Sockets.Socket class.

Comment: @ebyrob and carlos : sorry, its in the Stream class. changed the post accordingly.

Comment: I solved it using your recommendation...so far is working fine !!! thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 0):

See this thread:
[Is there a way to block on a socket send() until we get the ack for that packet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279205/is-there-a-way-to-block-on-a-socket-send-until-we-get-the-ack-for-that-packet)

It's the same for C# as for any other socket environment, you will have to do some kind of acknowledgement at the application level if you want to ensure receipt of data.

Sender tells receiver how much data to expect.  Receiver reads that many bytes and responds saying "i got it".  Sender is then free to close it's connection or go on about it's business.  If the Sender closes before receiving the "i got it" from the receiver data likely won't get there.

As to why your app level ack isn't working, post some code and we can take a look at it.